# importing a new installed module in my react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, mdbreact

I installed a module using npm install into my react project

```
npm install mdbreact --save
```

I checked then the nodemodules folder to make sure the lib was installed correctly and yes.
Now I am trying to import some components from the new lib like Input and Button
I am trying

```
import * as MDB from 'mdbreact';

import Input from 'mdbreact';
```

and I always get the error `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mdbreact'`
Any help how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: should be `import {Input} from 'mdbreact'`. But anyway I see you are using typescript. Have you tried deleting the folder from node_modules and install again. Then observe for any errors when you run `npm install mdbreact`

Comment: Input is exported as default in mdbreact, I tried {Input} and it did not work

Comment: I will try deleting and reinstalling and see

Comment: I tried reinstalling mdbreact and gave no errors but gave warnings. Anyway it is still giving the same erros, can not find module 'mdbreact'.

Comment: I tested this and works. With create-react-app-typescript. In my tsconfig.json  I have `"noImplicitAny": false`. Do you see any errors in the console when you run your solution? `import {Input} from 'mdbreact'` works for me but `import Input from 'mdbreact'` is undefined for me.

Comment: Thank you @Kunukn ! I will try it and report.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to look at how functions and variables are exported, so that you can see how they are imported.

I will explain further, but here are the docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

---

To export the `default` variable/function from a file you would use the `export default` phrase.

```
var testObj = { 'hello' : 'world' };
export default testObj;
```

To import the `default` variable/function from a file you would do it like so:

```
import testObj from './testFile';
```

To export a standard variable/function from a file you would use the standard `export` keyword.

```
var testObj = { 'hello' : 'world' };
var testObj2 = { 'hello' : 'again' };
export { testObj, testObj2 }; 
// or if you just want to export testObj - notice the default keyword is missing
export testObj;
```

To import a standard variable/function from a file you must wrap the imported variable/function inside braces.

#### TL;DR;

Only the default exported variable/function from a file can be imported without braces, anything else must be imported from within braces. `Input` is not the default export from `mdbreact` which is why it must be imported like so:

```
import { Input } from 'mdbreact';
```

`*` will import all available exports from the file, which is why that allowed your import to work. but you don't want to import all components from `mdbreact` on every file use `mdbreact` in or your project would become bloated very quickly.